# Separate Positive and Negative Samples for SVM Custom Object Detector

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, svm

I am trying to train a Custom Object Detector by using the HOG+SVM method on OpenCV.

I have managed to extract HOG features from my positive and negative samples using the below line of code:

```
import cv2

hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
def poshoggify():

        for i in range(1,20):
            image = cv2.imread("/Users/munirmalik/cvprojek/cod/pos/" + str(i)+ ".jpg")
            (winW, winH) = (500, 500)

            for resized in pyramid(image, scale=1.5):
                # loop over the sliding window for each layer of the pyramid
                for (x, y, window) in sliding_window(resized, stepSize=32, windowSize=(winW, winH)):
                    # if the window does not meet our desired window size, ignore it
                    if window.shape[0] != winH or window.shape[1] != winW:
                        continue

                    img_pos = hog.compute(image)
                    np.savetxt('posdata.txt',img_pos)

                    return img_pos
```

And the equivalent function for the negative samples.

How do I format the data in such a way that the SVM knows which is positive and which is negative?

Furthermore, how do I translate this training to the "test" of detecting the desired objects through my webcam?

Comment: which library/functionality do you want to use for svm training? Afaik typically you add a 1 or 0 or -1 or any other number per class

Comment: @Micka I'm good with either sklearn's svm or the built in SVM function in opencv. I'm not too sure what you mean by the number per class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do I format the data in such a way that the SVM knows which is positive and which is negative?**

You would now create another list called `labels` which would store the class value associated with a corresponding image. For example, if you have a training set of features that looks like this:

```
features = [pos_features1, pos_features2, neg_features1, neg_features2, neg_features3, neg_features4]
```

you would have a corresponding labels class like

```
labels = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

You would then feed this to a classifier like so:

```
clf=LinearSVC(C=1.0,  class_weight='balanced')
clf.fit(features,labels)
```

**Furthermore, how do I translate this training to the "test" of detecting the desired objects through my webcam?**

Before training, you should have split your labelled dataset (groundtruth) into training and testing datasets. You can do this using [skilearns KFold module](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html).

Comment: I've created the features and labels already. I've tried feeding them into my classifier but I get this error "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number". It's weird because they are all numbers. Do I need to format them further?

Comment: This should be asked as a separate question. It's tough to debug without seeing the actual line at which the error occurs,